Coverlet doesn't calculate code coverage for tests until another test is added
We have 700 tests in our solution and we use the latest .net and latest coverlet.
3 test files in 1 (out of 30) test solutions are not calculated correctly:

But the tests are executed:

The mysterious thing is, that as soon as I copy the files into another solution, where already 10 more tests are executed, they will be seen:

Even no of the other files touching the EmailService.
It feels like a very wierd bug in coverlet.
A few more insights and what I tried already:

it is the sae on my computer as another devs as in a pipeline
downgrading coverlet or another packages doesn't help
the 2 solutions are exactly the same and have nearly the same csproj etc.
When I delete all files from the solution I copied the test into, the remaining tests of the emailService will not be seen again. Means, only when other tests are present it works.
the tests itself are very boring, creating a service, calling a db, reading from it, Assert.Multiple + Assert.That and finished.

Example test:
    [Test]
    [AutoData]
    public void ApplyDesignTemplate_ValidInput_TemplateWithoutBodyUnchanged(
        DesignTemplateLogicService service,
        TranslationData data)
    {
        // Arrange
        string designTemplate = "This is a template without the body replacement token.";

        // Act
        var result = service.ApplyDesignTemplate(designTemplate, data);

        // Assert
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(designTemplate));
    }

Json Output stand alone:

Json Output with in touch of other tests:

Any ideas?
